# XHTML Validation Font error

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm currently trying to validate my XHTML and I'm confused on why this isn't valid:

```
<p><b><font size="5"/>Introduction></b></p>
```

Upon validation I'm getting the error "element "font" undefined".

How else would I increase the size of the text (without the use of CSS!) just within the XHTML code?  (It's for a school project hence the obscure request for no CSS)
Thanks.

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript to solve this?

Comment: JavaScript wouldn't be a real solution for this. It could either apply CSS programatically (violating the no CSS rule) or rearrange the DOM to add in invalid font elements (which would pass the validator only because it would be looking at the pre-scripted markup).

Comment: <font> is depreciated. Before it was depreciated it was used like this.

<font size="5">Introduction</font>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font element doesn't exist in the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype because it's obsolete. (It still validates as XHTML 1.0 Transitional though.)

> How else would I increase the size of the text (without the use of CSS!) just within the XHTML code? Thanks.

The whole point of writing XHTML (or any flavor of modern HTML really) is so that all presentation is handled by CSS, not the markup. If you insist on using markup to change the appearance of a page, you might as well use a legacy HTML doctype, or as mentioned, the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype if you really must use "XHTML".

Or, if you have learned about headings, use a proper heading element, such as `h1`:

```
<h1>Introduction</h1>
```

If your coursework insists that you only stick with what you have learned and it has not covered headings yet, then you're stuck with either using a transitional or legacy doctype, or cheating by using inline styles (which will still validate as XHTML 1.0 Strict, but technically involves CSS...).

Comment: its for a part 1 of school work where the second part would be adding CSS, but thanks for the reply anyway

Comment: @Moley: Well then your syllabus is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: It's a Computer Science degree at a top university. Basics then building up, don't be upset

Comment: @Moley: I'm not upset - I'm too jaded to care, much less be surprised. There doesn't appear to be a school in existence that is able to teach the basics correctly. Good thing I am self-taught.

Comment: 10/10 would attend "BoltClock's School of HTML/CSS and MLP"

Comment: @arronk6 this doesn't solve my issue so why would I accept it? (granted it is the most logical)

Comment: "any flavor of modern HTML really" - for values of "modern" equal to "newer than 1998"

Comment: @Moley - It does solve your issue. It tells you that you have to use Transitional or another legacy flavour of HTML (which is the only valid way to apply raw font size instructions in HTML).

Comment: Given the context, the proper solution is probably to use a header element (i.e. solve the problems that HTML was designed to solve) and let the presentation be a side effect of having a heading instead of a goal.

Comment: I'll take just use the h1 advice as it solves the issue, if you post it as a response I can give you the vote. Thanks

Comment: @Quentin: Good point, I was so fixated on the original question revolving around the font element that I missed this context entirely. I updated my answer.